# replacement of series expression

Tags: series-expansion

I want convert $$x^k\sum_{i=1}^\infty a[i]x^i$$
to $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a[i]x^{i+k}$$
by Mathematica,since it's timing consuming and worth a little to do it by hand.

from

```
x^k Sum[a[i]x^i,{i,1,Infinity}]
```

to

```
Sum[a[i]x^{i+k},{i,1,Infinity}]
```

I tried `Inactive` and `Factor` the expression but failed.

this works

```
x^k*Sum[x^i*a[i], {i, 1, Infinity}] /. 
   x^(n_)*Sum[x^(b_)*a[i], {i, 1, Infinity}] :> Sum[x^(b + n)*a[i], 
       {i, 1, Infinity}]
```

but I don't want to write such a bunch of codes each time.Is there other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rule = c1_. z_^(n1_.) Sum[c2_. z_^(n2_), iter_] :>
   c1 Sum[c2 z^(n1 + n2), iter];

(sum1 = x^k Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 1, Infinity}]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(sum2 = sum1 /. rule) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]